# If for every linear mapping image of convex set is compact then this set is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I have to answer the question: Is it true that if $K$ is convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and for every linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ image of $K$ is a compact interval, then $K$ is compact?

It's obvious that this set is bounded but I have a problem with closedness.

I tried to prove it using sequentially compact property, but I don't think  it is a good way to do that. Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Is it possible to use that the pre-image of a closed set is closed, under a continuous map? How much topology do you know?

Comment: Yes, we cen use it that pre-image of a closed set is closed. Euclidian topology we can use here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matt pointed out the closure of $K$ is a topological fact. If you want a more analytic approach then you could reason as follows: $K$ is closed if and only if given a converging sequence $\{x_n \}_n$ of points in the interior of $K$ then the limit of the sequence $y$ is still in $K$. Using that $K$ is convex we see that without loss of generality this sequence (hence the limit $y$) lies on a line $l$. Then we can consider the orthogonal projection $L \colon\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow l$: by continuity $\{L(x_n) \}$ converges to $L(y)$ and since the image $L(K)$ is compact it must be a closed subset of $l \cong \mathbb{R}$, therefore $L(y) \in L(K)$ but so we obtain a contradiction.

I tried to use arguments more familiar to analysis but the core of the proof is topology.

Comment: Thanks, I think I understood your proof. Could you show me how can we prove it in this trivial way? (:

Comment: In point-set topology a function $f$ between two topological spaces is continuous if and only if the preimage of an open subset is open. By De Morgan laws this is equivalent to the fact that the preimage of a closed subset is closed. In our case $f$ is a map between two euclidean spaces: you can easily define a topology on such spaces such that the above definition of continuous function I gave and the usual notion of continuous maps from analysis coincide.

Comment: I wanted to use this to get a a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and use that $f^{-1}(f(K))$ is continuous but it is clear that this I can find such a $f$ for which $f^{-1}(f(K))=K$. Sorry, my fault.

Comment: But why closure of K is topological fact?   Not for every function image of preimage of K is equal to K, so I don't know  how to see it :c